# How to expose activemq JMX MBeans via jboss web based jmx-console?

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, jmx

I have been trying to configure activemq such that the broker MBeans are available in jboss's web based jmx-console available at `http://localhost:8080/jmx-console`.

I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"     xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-    core.xsd">
<beans>
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="true"
        useShutdownHook="false">
        <!-- Use the following to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in JMX -->
        <managementContext>
            <!-- <managementContext createConnector="false" /> -->
            <managementContext>
                <MBeanServer>
                    <bean class="org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator"
                        factory-method="locateJBoss" xmlns="" />
                </MBeanServer>
            </managementContext>
        </managementContext>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

When I deploy the war the piece of xml gives error

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
```

Any idea how to make activemq MBeans integrate with jboss web based jmx-console?

Default settings with just createConnector=false won't work for me because jboss is configured to **not** use 1099 RMI port. LocateJboss factory-method call on org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator is the only way (I know of) to get jboss MBeanServer handle.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spring JMX do](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jmx.html)c, you could try something like this :

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
     <property name="server">
       <bean id="mBeanServerLocator" class="org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator" 
                    factory-method="locateJBoss" />
     </property>
  </bean>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="true"
        useShutdownHook="false">
        <!-- Use the following to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in JMX -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext MBeanServer="exporter"/>     
            <!-- I am not sure what MBeanServer attribute is waiting for (a ref, an id, something else ...)-->
        </managementContext>
    </broker>
```

Comment: After trying out this code Spring complains that "exporter" should be a string and not a bean reference in the line <managementContext MBeanServer="exporter"/>